# trim spaces on captured group regex

Tags: regex, trim

after searching everywhere,  [How can whitespace be trimmed from a Regex capture group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906492/how-can-whitespace-be-trimmed-from-a-regex-capture-group), seems to have the closest thing, and I can almost taste it,  but still no cigar.... 
So here goes, for my very first post to StackOverflow.....

I am trying to capture Exactly 27 characters of a string (for reasons that really don't matter).

So I used regex: `.{27}`

on this string `"Joey Went to the Store and found some great steaks!"`

the result was `"Joey Went to the Store and "`

Bingo exactly 27 characters.
But that result is causing errors in my program because of the trailing space. So now I need to also take that result and trim the space after "and " to return the result without the trailing space.   the final result needs to be `"Joey Went to the Store and"`.

here's the kicker, I need it to all work from a single regex because the application can only apply 1 regex (really dumb program, but I'm stuck with it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this regex:

```
^.{26}[^\s]?
```

It will match 26 characters starting from beginning of line and will match the 27th only if it is not a white space character. See the demo below for more details.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZ0uU9/1)

Comment: Thank you lbarros.  your answer worked... until I also realized there might be times when the input string might be shorter than 26/27 characters.   your solution stops matching if the string is shorter.  Saleem's answer allowed me to add 1 small component to your answer to come up with the final solution. `^.{1,26}[^\s]?` allows up to 26 + the 27th if not whitespace.  Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Awesome, good job on combining the two answers to meet your requirements. Team work!!!